# New Simple Volume with greyed when add a new Hard Disks

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, disk-space

On the Disk Management panel that cannot choose "New Simple Volume". How to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to fix this issue
Step 1: To click right-mouse button and choice Initialize Disk
[image]

[image]

Step 2:  To pick up MBR

Step 3: Done
[image]